# Verse where King responds Angrily to Jerimiah's message to surrender

Tags: verse-identification

Not sure if this was Jerimiah or another prophet (or I may be making it up entirely). The king was preparing to fight the invasion, and was delivered a message from the lord not to fight with arms. The king responds with something emotional along the lines of you would have the city/nation destroyed.

To be clear, it was not Jeremiah 38:4

> Then the officials said to the king, “This man ought to die, for he is discouraging the warriors who remain in this city, as well as all the people, by speaking such words to them; this man is not seeking the well-being of these people, but their ruin.

Probably no anything from Isaiah either.

Comment: Welcome to C.se Tom. Please take the Tour (below left) to get situated. Your question is going to receive some downvotes but don't be discouraged.  Since verse-identification is a valid tag here I hope the question will not be closed.

Comment: Verse identification questions need to specify the *exact* wording you've already tried searching for, as well as any passages those results returned that are *not* the passage you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

In chapter 36 of Jeremiah there is an account of his scribe, Baruch, reading in front of all the people in the temple the prophetic message of Jeremiah. That included the message not to resist the invaders. Baruch was then summoned to take the scroll he had read from, and read it to the princes. They were fearful, telling Baruch and Jeremiah to hide before they then took the scroll to let king Jehoiakim (king of Judah) hear the prophecy.

It was winter-time, and there was a fire in the hearth. After three or four leaves of the scroll had been read out, the king took a knife, sliced those bits off and cast them into the fire. The was done to all the scroll. He then wanted Baruch and Jeremiah brought to him, but the Lord had hidden them.

Neither that chapter, nor the next one (which you say is not it) goes against the biblical admonition to trust in God to provide food while still taking action to do farm-work yourself. This is about a second threatened invasion that would finish off Jerusalem and the remaining people, and God saying how to avoid catastrophe (by not resisting the invaders). The king and the people chose to resist, and so catastrophe befell them, as God had warned it would, if they ignored the prophetic word. **The people here did *not* trust God. They disobeyed him and took their own action, and so were finished off.**

Answer (score 0):

The description of the verse/s in question fits well with the general attitude of Jeremiah - that Babylon was God's agent to punish Judah and should not be resisted. The following may be the prophecy you are looking for, although the king's response is not an exact match.

Jeremiah 38

> Jeremiah then said to Zedekiah: “Thus says the Lord God of hosts, the
> God of Israel: If you will only surrender to the princes of Babylon’s
> king, you shall save your life; this city shall not be destroyed by
> fire, and you and your household shall live. 18 But if you do not
> surrender to the princes of Babylon’s king, this city shall fall into
> the hand of the Chaldeans, who shall destroy it by fire, and you shall
> not escape their hand.”
>
> 19 King Zedekiah said to Jeremiah, “I am afraid of the Judahites who
> have deserted to the Chaldeans; I could be handed over to them, and
> they will mistreat me.”

Comment: That's not it sorry, I guess downvotes are fair. I'll have to listen to Jeremiah again, and answer this myself. I thought would be an interesting verse, because it goes against the "I trust God to provide, but still plant my crops (work a day job)" argument, but for self-defence (or god forbid national defence).

Comment: Or, as the Muslims say, "Trust in Allah, but tie your camel to the fence." Let us know if you find it.